# CSS Animation from Left to Right

Tags: html, css, animation

I am trying to make an animation in `CSS`. I read some examples of it online and I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong...
I want my potato image to go from left to right and then turn around and then go back to the left side again, but I probably messed up something in my code? Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong or how I should face this problem instead?

Here is my code:

```css
#pot {
  bottom: 15%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation: linear infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation-name: run;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes run {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  50% {
    right: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
    , webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="pot">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgNyF.png?s=328&g=1" width=100px height=100px>
</div>
```

(sorry mos, safari and opera users)
https://jsfiddle.net/oxc12av7/

Comment: try using `50%{ left : 100%;}` rather than `50%{ right : 0;}` - that worked for me in your fiddle

Comment: ah it worked, thanks alot @Andrew !

Comment: I removed "[solved in comments]" from the question's title in an edit. Either post your own answer, accept one that was given or delete the question.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Since this question is still getting alot of attention and none of the soulotions yet provide the full answer that I was trying to achieve, I'll give an example how I solved it some years ago.

> First to make the animation go left to right, like many other questions have showed:

```css
#pot {
  bottom: 15%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation: linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: run;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes run {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  50% {
    left: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;    
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="pot">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgNyF.png?s=328&g=1" width=100px height=100px>
</div>
```

The problem with only this solution is that the potato goes too far to the right so it gets pushed out from the viewport before turning around. As the user Taig suggested we can use `transform: translate` solution, but we can also just set `50% { left: calc(100% - potatoWidth); }`

> Second to make the animation go left to right, without getting pushed
> out from viewport:

```css
#pot {
  bottom: 15%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation: linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: run;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes run {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  50% { 
    left: calc(100% - 100px); 
   }
  100% {
    left: 0;     
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="pot">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgNyF.png?s=328&g=1" width=100px height=100px>
</div>
```

And lastly to make potato turn around which I also asked for in the question. To do that we need to change the transform around it's y-axis.

Note that if we make it turn around only at 50% it will slowly turn around at the same time it's moving. So we need to specify how long the potato should be at `-webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);`. In this example the potato doesn't turn until it's 48% into the animation, then it's able to turn in the span of 48% to 50%.

> Third to make the potato turn around in each corner so it doesn't move backwards:

```css
#pot {
  bottom: 15%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation: linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: run;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes run {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  48% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg); 
  }
  50% { 
    left: calc(100% - 100px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); 
  }
  98% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); 
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;    
     -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="pot">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgNyF.png?s=328&g=1" width=100px height=100px>
</div>
```

Answer (score 19):

you have to use only the 'left' not the 'right' parameter on your keyframe. You have also some typo on your css, the 'scale' seems useless too.

```
#pot{
    bottom:15%;
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-animation:linear infinite alternate;
    -webkit-animation-name: run;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
}     
@-webkit-keyframes run {
    0% { left: 0;}
    50%{ left : 100%;}
    100%{ left: 0;}
}
```

like : [online version](http://codepen.io/empreintes/pen/jyWQym)

Comment: use of alternate for animation direction is redundant, and the code will behave the same without it or using `normal` for the animation direction, as the alternating effect is handled in the key-frames definition.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer has the flaw that the element is completely pushed out of the viewport during the animation. This might be desired for some use cases, but I wanted to share a cleaner solution that leverages the CSS `transform: translate` property.

```css
#pot {
  bottom: 15%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  animation: linear infinite alternate;
  animation-name: run;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes run {
    0% {
      left: 0;
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
      left: 100%;
      transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}
```

```html
<img id="pot" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgNyF.png?s=328&g=1" width="100px" height="100px" />
```

I wrote in a bit more detail about this technique here: https://medium.com/@taig/dynamically-position-and-center-an-html-element-with-css-based-on-percentage-5fea0799a589.

Comment: Would you add edition for pushed out the screen to max right such as Browser notification.

Answer (score 4):

see the below code it working fine.in the below code when you hover on the potato it runs the image from left to right when you hover back at that time it returns to the left again.while object 3 div runs from left to right whenever you refresh the page there are 2 examples are there you can use anyone.

```css
.object {
    position: absolute;
}

.van {
    top: 45%;
    left: 44%;
}

#axis:hover .move-right{
    transform: translate(350px,0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(350px,0); /** Chrome & Safari **/
    -o-transform: translate(350px,0); /** Opera **/
    -moz-transform: translate(350px,0); /** Firefox **/
}

.object {
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out; /** Chrome & Safari **/
    -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out; /** Firefox **/
    -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out; /** Opera **/
}

.object3 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0%   {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
    25%  {background-color:yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
  /*  50%  {background-color:blue; left:200px; top:200px;}
    75%  {background-color:green; left:0px; top:200px;}
    100% {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}*/
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
    0%   {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
    25%  {background-color:yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
  /*  50%  {background-color:blue; left:200px; top:200px;}
    75%  {background-color:green; left:0px; top:200px;}
    100% {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}*/
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="axis" class="one">
            <img class="object van move-right" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgNyF.png?s=328&g=1" width=100px height=100px>
        </div>
        <div class="object3"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is awesome! Any idea how to make the potato loop infinitely from left to right? So now it's left to right; done; right to left; done; ...etc

Can it be done left to right; done; left to right; done etc?

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    animation-name :example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: 3
}


@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0%   {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
    25%  {background-color:yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
    100% {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
}


</style>
</head>
<body>
```

**Check this example, which moves a block of red div to right and then back to left**