# CSS background-position animation not working

Tags: html, css, background-position, background-size

I have a background image that I want to continuously scroll from right to left. I want the image to cover the entire screen, but when I set `background-size: cover;` it does not animate at all. How can I fix this?

> HTML

```
<body>
  ...
</body>
```

> CSS

```
body {
  background-color: rgb(15, 5, 40);
  background-image: url('./images/star background.png');
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: top left;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: myMove 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes myMove {
  from { background-position-x: right; }

  to { background-position-x: left }
}
```

If I set `background-size #px #px;` or `initial` or `X% Y%` then it works fine, but doesn't cover the whole screen? Also, here is the image:
[image]

Comment: share you png image

Comment: read [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41587802/css-animation-from-left-to-right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41587802/css-animation-from-left-to-right)

Comment: @TemaniAfif I tried to put in the picture, but it is white stars on a clear background, so you couldn't even see it.

Comment: we can make that background color different. I suppose this is what you did to see it

Comment: I have posted the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another idea using translate on pseudo element where you make the element big to have enough room for an infinite movement:

```css
html::before {
  content:"";
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0; /* change to right for the opposite direction */
  bottom:0;
  width:200%;
  background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJKLc.png) 0/50% auto;
  animation:move 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  to {transform:translateX(-50%);} /* change to "50%" for the opposite direction */
}
```

Comment: @SharkCoding simply copy the code, what I gave is an *implementation*

Comment: I am getting some weird glitches with the images and buttons that I want on the screen. The image doesn't show, and when I hover over the button, the hover effect flashes on and off?

Comment: Also, I replaced my current code with the code above so maybe that was wrong?