# How to make animation of width from 0 to 100% from right to left?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am looking to animate a DIV from right to left.
I know how to make it from left to right but i am not sure how to do it from right to left.

Below is the code for animation from left to right::

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.contents {
  background: #c3c;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper:hover .contents {
  transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
  width: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="contents">These are the contents of this div</div>
</div>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: hi, perhaps reversing this might do the trick https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41587802/css-animation-from-left-to-right

Comment: text-align:right on the parent container?

Comment: Thank you so much, text-align: right solved my problem.

Comment: You should move "transition: width 1s ease-in-out;" to the main .contents for a smooth rollback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider clip-path and you can easily have any direction

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.contents {
  background: #c3c;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  width:100%;
  transition: clip-path 1s ease-in-out;
  clip-path:inset(0);
}

.wrapper:hover .contents {
  clip-path:inset(0 100% 0 0); /* top "right" bottom left*/
}

.wrapper.alt:hover .contents {
  clip-path:inset(0 0 0 100%); /* top right bottom "left"*/
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="contents">These are the contents of this div</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper alt">
  <div class="contents">These are the contents of this div</div>
</div>
```

Or simply rely on text-align:

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.wrapper.alt {
  text-align:right;
}

.contents {
  background: #c3c;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align:left;
  transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
}

.wrapper:hover .contents {
  width: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="contents">These are the contents of this div</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper alt">
  <div class="contents">These are the contents of this div</div>
</div>
```