# Make the icon slide from left to right on mouseenter

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to move the garbage icon move from left to right on mouse enter event but I am unable to do so. Right now it just comes up when I just hover my mouse in the li tag. Can anyone help me with the code? I am a beginner in Java Script so help is appreciated.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>ToDo List!</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css">
    <style>
    .span-trash{
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: red;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 5px;
    }
    ul, li {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        display: block;
    }
    .done{
        text-decoration: line-through;
    }

    #delete {
        margin-right: 5px;  
    }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("ul").on("click", "li", function(){
                $(this).toggleClass("done");
            });

            $("ul").on("mouseenter", "li", function() {
                $(this).find("span").show();
                $(".span-trash").on("click", function() {
                    $(this).parent().remove();
                })
            });

            $("ul").on("mouseleave", "li", function() {
                $(this).find("span").hide();
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li><span class="span-trash" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Item 1</li>
        <li><span class="span-trash" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Item 2</li>
        <li><span class="span-trash" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Item 3</li>
    </ul>                
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use the CSS pseudoselector [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) and [add an animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41587802/css-animation-from-left-to-right). Don't show and hide things using jQuery - whatever guide you're getting that from is very old.

Comment: Can you just help me with the code?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `margin-left` and `transition` to simulate a slide-in animation.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>ToDo List!</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css">
    <style>
    .span-trash{
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        display: inline-block; 
        background-color: red;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 5px;
        margin-left: -50px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        transition: margin 1s;
    }
    li:hover .span-trash {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    ul, li {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .done{
        text-decoration: line-through;
    }
    #delete {
        margin-right: 5px;  
    }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("ul").on("click", "li", function(){
                $(this).toggleClass("done");
            });

            // $("ul").on("mouseenter", "li", function() {
            //     $(this).find("span").show();

            $(".span-trash").on("click", function() {
                $(this).parent().remove();
            })

            // });

            // $("ul").on("mouseleave", "li", function() {
            //     $(this).find("span").hide();
            // });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li><span class="span-trash"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Item 1</li>
        <li><span class="span-trash"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Item 2</li>
        <li><span class="span-trash"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Item 3</li>
    </ul>                
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why did you comment the js part? How to enable animation and use the js code

Comment: @Coderash, I commented out some of your JavaScript because it is an overly complicated approach when you can just use `:hover` in CSS. The rest of the JavaScript is still there and you can see that the animation works.