# CSS animation to move a button from left to right when clicked

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I want my button to move from the left to the right when I click it. I think I have everything I need, but apparently I have either left something out or I'm not put something in the right order. Why won't my box move? Do I need to use JavaScript? The HTML has nothing more than a button with the class name of box.

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  border: none;
  margin: 100px 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animation-name: move-right;
}

.box :hover{
  background-color: red;
}

.box :active {
  transition: all 2s linear;
}

@keyframes move-right {
  transform: translateX(350px,0);
}
```

Comment: Please share your HTML

Comment: translateX should only have one parameter. Also your hover and active selectors should not be space-separated from the class names.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41587802/css-animation-from-left-to-right
I think you have your question answered here if not come here

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use javascript to monitor the click event.

Tips

1. The animation name should be removed from the `.box` class.
2. The hover effect is the same color as the default state, if you want to show that something is happening it cannot be the same color.
3. The translateX() takes one value, unless you intended to use the translate(X, Y) which takes two values.
4. When animating you do not use transition timing, animation has it own timing.